# Если у предложения интонация вопросительная, то запятая не ставится?

Tags: пунктуация

*«В каких случаях можно обратиться за льготным периодом и какие документы необходимо предоставить в банк»*

Написано верно? Без запятой?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае вопросительная интонация предложения, конечно, играет роль, но самым главным является наличие относительно-вопросительного (в данном случае вопросительного) местоимения "какие". Запятая ставиться, разумеется, не будет. Можно даже провести параллель с этим же словом, употреблением в придаточном предложении, где, как мы знаем, запятой нет.

Comment: Привет! Что-то редко вы у нас бываете, а я вас помню. Заходите почаще и отвечайте на вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

Написано верно, запятой нет. Запятая не ставится в ССП, обе части которых соединены союзом И (ИЛИ) и являются вопросительными предложениями.

Классический пример: *Ты понял меня или ударить тебя?*

Comment: даже если без вопросительного знака?

Comment: @flossyU: я вот не пойму, как может быть вопросительная интонация без вопросительного знака?

Comment: ну в данном случае, это типа подзаголовка, после которого идет двоеточие и перечисляются документы и тд...

Comment: А-а, ясно. Тогда простите, что поставил "?".

Comment: то-то я не могу понять, откуда у моего предложения появился ?))